# Where should I place the .htpasswd file (phpMyAdmin)?

Tags: apache2, lamp, phpmyadmin, .htaccess

I am following this tutorial setting up phpMyAdmin:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-12-04

I edit the .htaccess file at /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess

But I need to point it to a .htpasswd file of my choice.

Can I put it in /usr/share/phpmyadmin so it's next to .htaccess? Or can I put it in /var/www ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is NOT a good idea to place your `.htpasswd` file in `/var/www`.

You can place the `.htpasswd` pretty much anywhere other than your web folder. I would place it in `/etc/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: What is the difference between /etc/phpmyadmin and /usr/share/phpmyadmin?

Comment: So why is .htaccess being instructed (as per the tutorial) to go into /usr/share and not /etc/phpmyadmin since .htaccess is a sort of configuration type file?

Comment: As long as `.htpasswd` is not accessible from http, ftp, etc, it's Ok to place it anywhere, including `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.

The main difference has to do with the intended use of each folder. I personally like `/etc` for the important stuff better.

Comment: Ah... `.htaccess` files are special. Those are usually supposed to be in `/var/www`. The reason for that difference is because you may want to decide that you need different configurations for each subdirectory on your server, so you can place one `htaccess` file in each. In the case of phpmyadmin, the PHP interpreter reads the `.htaccess` file from that place instead of `/var/www`, but that is exactly the same reason why it shouldn't have the `.htpasswd` file in the same place. **Rule: If a folder is accessible by a process accessing the network, the folder can be compromised**

Answer (score 1):

Well, in theory you should be ok with putting your .htpasswd file anywhere in the apache document root since apache default configuration for any file beginning with ".ht" should be this:

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

However, I tend to avoid that, and usually put my .htpasswd files somwhere in the apache folder, for example:

```
/etc/apache2/htpass/.htpasswd
```

or

```
/etc/apache2/.htpasswd
```

I don't think there are any official best practices for this, correct me if I am wrong...